# Show * characters on PasswordType Field

Tags: symfony

I need to show "*" characters on a PasswordType Field (or TextType Field) instead of the clear password for editing a user.

This field is saved on a DB, this is important that only the display change.

For example:

Actual:
[image: Actual display]
Expected :[image: Expected display]

I don't find anything about that in the official documentation.

UP:

Code of the VisiteurType.php:

```html
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nom', TextType::class)
        ->add('prenom', TextType::class)
        ->add('login', TextType::class)
        ->add('mdp', PasswordType::class, array('always_empty' => false))
            [etc.]
    }
```

Code of the form.html.twig:

```html
   <div class="password-type">
            {{ form_label(visiteurForm.mdp, null, { 'label_attr':  {
                'class': 'col-sm-4 control-label'
            }}) }}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ form_errors(visiteurForm.mdp) }}
                {{ form_widget(visiteurForm.mdp, { 'attr':  {
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'rows': '8'
                }}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

It broke my design: [image: Broken design]

Comment: Are you using a [`PasswordType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/password.html) field? Please show your code for the form

Comment: No ! Thank you !

Comment: So it works now?

Comment: If I put any caracter on field, it work. But now the field don't show anything (however I've add the array('always_empty' => false) on buildForm. I think is specific to PasswordType no ? (I've updated the OP with you're correction)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<input type="password" id="password"></input>
```

by type ="password" it will show "*" instead of text value

Comment: I actually use the ->add('mdp', TextType::class) on a class who extends of AbstractType. Is it possible ?